# Not enough inputs arguments , matlab function

Tags: matlab, function, syntax-error

I am having some problems defining a simple function in Matlab, the error says: not enough input arguments! but the function only needs one argument.
The input is `A`, a matrix (100 rows, 4 columns)
and what I expect is another matrix.

I save `MyFun.m` as a file in order to call it later with `@MyFun`.

```
function [y]= MyFun(A)

a=[nanmean(A(:,3)),nanmean(A(:,4))];

b=sqrt(a(:,1).^2+a(:,2).^2);

c=((atan2d(a(:,2),a(:,1)))./2)+90;

if c<=90

    c=c+90;  

else

    c=c-90;
end

d=[nanstd(A(:,3)),nanstd(A(:,4))];

y=[a,b,c,d]

clear a b c d
end
```

Comment: I suspect that you have a variable or function also called "MyFun" in your workspace , I suggest you clear your workspace and try again.

Comment: Are you passing an argument to your function? Something like 
`A = rand(100,4);
y = MyFun(A)`

That works well for me. Your code runs just fine.

Comment: Call your function using parentheses: `MyFun(input)`, by adding an `@` you are creating a function handle instead of executing the function. But without more info on how you call the function, we cannot answer your question.

Comment: Also note that `Myfun` and `MyFun` are not the same. The file name is the name of the function you call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with what you have.  I 2nd what Y.Chang said about making sure you don't have another variable or function called MyFun.

The other issues might be:

1. You clear your variables at the end. Having the clear and end on the same line might do something wonky.  I would just remove that since those variables will be cleared automatically when the function exits.
2. It depends on how you call it when you use the @ notation.  You need to be sure the input parameter is being passed in correctly there.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your observations. Just to clarify some points: 

1. I define A=rand(100,4)


2. Code works well when I evaluate it with out the first sentence (function [y]= MyFun(A))


3. My workplace is clear and I don't have another function or variable with the name "MyFun"